# angular2 is not in DefinitelyTyped repo?

Tags: typescript, angular, definitelytyped, tsd

Maybe my understanding of what DefinitelyTyped contains is wrong.. but I would imagine that I should be able to find the Angular2 typings in this repo, no? - I.e. 'tsd install angular2' doesn't find anything, and I can't find it in the repo anymore, neither.

I found some old [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angular2.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/) that contain them.. but that one seems to refer to an alpha version only.

So in short: where can I get the latest Angular2 typings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find angular2 definitions (*.d.ts) files in node_modules/angular2/ folder.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation - it's just irritating because the Typings now look quite different and are spread over hundreds of files. :T

Comment: libraries sometimes have definitions included into node package

Comment: Yes, understood.. it's just that there is not a single "angular2.d.ts" file where I can find all the typings. Basically I will always have to have the full node package around, I can not only extract the typings.